# Error - Web Project using Tomcat server and Spring MVC framework in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

The first project that I using Spring. I didn't use Maven. Please, help me! I get error this.  If you want to see my code, I will share it. Thank you.

```
**
```

> > ```
> > 27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
> > INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on
> > ```
> >
> > the
> >     java.library.path: C:\Program
> >     Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Sybase\IQ-15_2\bin32;C:\Sybase\IQ-15_2\bin64;C:\Oracle\Administrator\product\client\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
> >     Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\x64\;C:\Program Files
> >     (x86)\IBM\Personal Communications\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Trace
> >     Facility\;.
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
> >         WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
> >     property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:springornek'
> >     did not find a matching property.
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
> >         INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
> >         INFO: Initialization processed in 272 ms
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
> >         INFO: Starting service Catalina
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
> >         INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.44
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
> >         INFO: Marking servlet springornek as unavailable
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
> >         SEVERE: Servlet /springornek threw load() exception
> >         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
> >             at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
> >             at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.(DispatcherServlet.java:188)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4425)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4738)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
> >             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
> >         INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
> >         INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
> >         INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/10  config=null
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:17 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
> >         INFO: Server startup in 320 ms
> >         27.Ağu.2015 09:39:19 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
> >         INFO: Servlet springornek is currently unavailable

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your log says, apache commons logging classes are not found..
So add the jar of apache commons logging in your lib.
Here you can get that jar http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging

```
SEVERE: Servlet /springornek threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory at
```

NOTE: Use maven or gradle to simplify building projects dependencies for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Anudeep! I see in log that **Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springornek-servlet.xml]** And I moved springornek-servlet.xml into WEB-INF. It's solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have all the required jar's in the lib directory.

the good part with maven it will pull all the versions you specify and put it into WEB-INF/lib

If you want to start without maven or gradle you should do things one step at a time. Make a simple web app with web.xml and then add 1 thing at a time.

Post your web.xml so that we can help you.

The below is nothing to be scared off for your local development but is just an info

```
The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
My web.xml is :

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.4">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>springornek</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>springornek</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>

My springornek-servlet is :

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
    <beans>
        <bean id="basitDenetimci" class="denetim.BasitDenetimci" />
        <bean id="urlEsleme"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="/index.htm">basitDenetimci</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="gorunumCozumleyici"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass">
                <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
            </property>
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

My springornek Class is :

    package denetim;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

    public class BasitDenetimci implements Controller{

        @Override
        public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
                HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
            return new ModelAndView("basit");
        }

    }

My index.jsp is : 

    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <c:redirect url="/index.htm"/>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>

My basit.jsp is :

    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9">
    <title>springornek</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>

Jars that I using :

jstl-1.2.jar
jstl-api-1.2-sources.jar
jstl-connector-3.0.jar
spring.jar
spring-aop.jar
spring-beans-3.1.1.release-sources.jar
spring-context.jar
spring-core.jar
spring-dao.jar
spring-mock.jar
spring-orm.jar
spring-web.jar
spring-webmvc.jar
```

Comment: This link will be helpful :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055602/why-we-need-apache-common-logging-jars-to-install-spring-framework-in-eclipse