# Spring HelloWorld : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

**Edit : I have copy pasted another **

I am simply trying to implement Spring HelloWorld example .
My Spring version is 4.5 , jdk 5.1
I am trying to do it without maven , Just imported spring JAR in eclipse

1. my main class(Student.java)

   ```
   package com.javatpoint;  

   public class Student {  
   private String name;  

   public String getName() {  
       return name;  
   }  

   public void setName(String name) {  
       this.name = name;  
   }  

   public void displayInfo(){  
       System.out.println("Hello: "+name);  
   }  
   }
   ```
2. my spring.xml

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-
   3.0.xsd">  

    <bean id="studentbean" class="com.javatpoint.Student">  
    <property name="name" value="Vimal Jaiswal"></property>
   ```

---

3.Test.java

```
         package com.javatpoint;  

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  

import com.javatpoint.Student;

public class Test {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  

    Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");  
    student.displayInfo();  
}  
}
```

---

still it is saying  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

---

is it anything I am missing , do i need to integrate with maven . kindly suggest

this is my error stack

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.<init>(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.<init>(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractBeanFactory.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:67)
    at com.javatpoint.Test.main(Test.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Hi, which class is been not found? I think it could be a duplicated jar error...

Comment: You should mention full qualified classname in class="testClass" instead of testClass

Comment: Are you sure about the versions ? Why XML and not Java configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

I can see you have copied some code from a tutorial.

But you didn't copied correctly.

You have defined your bean in spring.xml like below,

```
<bean id="helloBean" class="testClass">
    <property name="name" value="Mkyong" />
</bean>
```

But there is no class with name **testClass** with variable **name**

I think, now you can do the rest of things

Comment: Your getter didn't returns anything.

Comment: apache.commons.logging is required for spring, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14055668/4090550

Comment: When you use maven dependency it automatically downloads all related dependencies, but in case you are manually adding dependencies you have to add all required jars to your classpath

Answer (score 0):

This exception mainly happen when you are not imported `commons-logging-1.1.3.jar`. Go to Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs. Select `commons-logging-1.1.3.jar` and apply.

Comment: that's exaclty the solution to the OP problem, I cannot understand why you had a downvote ! My current issue is : if apache commons logging is needed by spring, why is it not a dependency (in pom) ?